# is there a way to show data in repeater field form after repeater is extended?

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

i did this in `plugin.php` boot function to addfield in repeater field

```
WartaRutin::extendFormFields(function($form){ 

        if(!$model instanceof Kebaktian) return;

        if(!$form->model->kebum) return;

        if(!$form->isNested) return;                       

            $form->addFields([

              'addition' => [
                     'label' => 'addition label',
                     'span' => 'storm',
                     'cssClass' => 'col-sm-4',
                     'type' => 'text']

        ]);      

});
```

the result produce additional field perfectly.. the problem is after data is saved, it doesn`t show in the form but data exist in database,,

how should i solve this..

Comment: i guess you need to take inpit from user in some structured way store in database then you need to update/append that `structured data` using this https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#extend-form-fields

Comment: great reference.. so in my condition.. `$form->addFields()` become `$form->kebum->addFields()` am i right?

Comment: this method is adding new fields or remove the existing and then add new fields

Comment: i am guessing that we dont need to worries about database fields name.. since field name inside repeater field will be save as string array for repeater field name in database..

Comment: hmm need to check that

Comment: actually i just checked all models.. it happens for  all repeater field that i create.. i guess since i add backend users id in all model.. do we need to extend query for the repeater field..

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are correct we dont need to worry about database fields.

as `repeater field` is build of `json` so `in database its json` and when you fetch from database its `array`

> just take structured input from user then use :  `extend-form-fields` octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#extend-form-fields

now you can add and remove fields from the repeater as user needed.

if any doubts please comment

Comment: sir i have figure it out but bumped into another problem.. question updated